# Why is decimal precision culture dependent?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, internationalization

I wrote a test performing an assertion on a formatted string, when I noticed that the number of decimals in a string formatted with the percent format specifier (`P`) was different on some cultures.

In the example below, `en-US` uses two decimal digits, while the other sampled cultures use three.

What is the heuristic behind this? Is there a way, other than rounding, of normalizing the different cultures to the same precision?

```cs
Console.WriteLine(0.19999d.ToString("P", new CultureInfo("en-US"))); // "20.00%"
Console.WriteLine(0.19999d.ToString("P", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))); // "19.999%"
Console.WriteLine(0.19999d.ToString("P", new CultureInfo("en"))); // "19.999%"
Console.WriteLine(0.19999d.ToString("P", new CultureInfo("nb-NO"))); // "19,999 %"
Console.WriteLine(0.19999d.ToString("P", new CultureInfo("nl-NL"))); // "19,999%"
```

Runtime: 6.0.9
Platform: Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different because that's what those cultures have determined to be appropriate. If you want a specific number of decimal places rather than accepting the culture-specific default then include that in your format specifier, e.g. "P2".

Aletrnatively, you can create your own `CultureInfo` or `NumberFormatInfo` that sets the relevant properties as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In other words, it is determined by the given cultures' `NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits`, which in turn is fetched from [Win32 NLS](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/CultureData.Nls.cs) on WIndows. This value can be changed to my liking, so I'll just do that.